# How do I open a TCSession?

Tags: java, soa, plm, catia

I'm working with Teamcenter and Catia via the Java SOA libraries.  I'm running into an issue where the demo code appears broken and I can't find a good example or documentation to work towards.  The following code results in a null value exception.  Specifically the line "session = PortalContext.getContext().getSession();" is where I'm crashing.

```
package com.ebsolutions.catiman.actions;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

/*
 * Tc java classes 
 */
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCSession;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentItemRevision;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentItem;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentItemType;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentDataset;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentBOMWindow;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentBOMWindowType;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentBOMLine;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentRevisionRuleType;
import com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponentForm;
import com.teamcenter.rac.aif.kernel.AIFComponentContext;
import com.teamcenter.rac.aif.kernel.InterfaceAIFComponent;

/*
 * Catia integration java classes 
 */
import com.ebsolutions.catiman.ErrorWarningMessages;
import com.ebsolutions.catiman.PortalContext;
import com.ebsolutions.catiman.commands.TClassUserLUSCommand;


/**
 * Sample file. 
 * This class is not launched by the CATIAV5 integration
 *
 * @date 02/06/2008
 */
public class SampleIndependentSilentLUS 
{
     /**
      * Current TC session: needed to access Tc server (service.call)
      * null value is not allowed.
      */
     protected TCSession session = null;

     /**
      * This flag defines wether the LUS should be performed in silent mode or not
      */
     protected boolean is_silent[];

     /**
      * title of the messages
      */
     private String _title = "Sample Independent SilentLUS";

     /**
      * components that contains the assembly to LUS. 
      */
     private TCComponentItem[] item = null;
     private TCComponentItemRevision[] item_revision = null;
     private TCComponentDataset[] part_dataset = null;
     private TCComponentDataset[] product_dataset = null;
     private TCComponentDataset[] drawing_dataset = null;
     private TCComponentForm[] other = null;
     private TCComponentBOMWindow bom_window[] = null;

     /**
      * The constructor.
      */
     public SampleIndependentSilentLUS()
     {
         /* try to find the TCSession
         note: this is not the only way to retrieve the TCSession. */
         session = PortalContext.getContext().getSession();
     }

     /* --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
     /*
      * Sample main function
      * @date 02/06/2008
      */
     public void customerProcess() {

          showInformationMessage("START of silent LUS");
          TClassUserLUSCommand silent_lus_command = null;


          /*
           * example of searching items to LUS
           */
          int return_value = findItemToLUS();
          if (return_value < 0)
          {
               /* Unable to find any item to LUS */
               return;
          }


          /**
           * Initialize the API
           */
          silent_lus_command = new TClassUserLUSCommand(session);

          /*
           * API: LUS process.
           * call the "executeLUS" function
           */
          /*******  Item  ********/
          try
          {
               if (item[0] != null)
               {
                    silent_lus_command.executeLUS(item[0], is_silent[0]);
                    showInformationMessage("pause in silent LUS after Item");
               }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("SampleLUS error (1) Exception : " + ex);
          }


          /*******  Item Revision  ********/
          try
          {
               if (item_revision[1] != null)
               {
                    silent_lus_command.executeLUS(item_revision[1], is_silent[1]);
                    showInformationMessage("pause in silent LUS after Item_rev");
               }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("SampleLUS error (2) Exception : " + ex);
          }


          /*******  bom window  ********/
          try
          {
               if (bom_window[2] != null)
               {
                    silent_lus_command.executeLUS(bom_window[2], is_silent[2]);
                    showInformationMessage("pause in silent LUS after bom_widow");
               }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("SampleLUS error (3) Exception : " + ex);
          }


          /******* CATPart dataset  ********/
          try
          {
               if (part_dataset[3] != null)
               {
                    silent_lus_command.executeLUS(part_dataset[3], is_silent[3]);
                    showInformationMessage("pause in silent LUS after CATPart");
               }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("SampleLUS error (4) Exception : " + ex);
          }


          /******* CATProduct dataset  ********/
          try
          {
               if (product_dataset[4] != null)
               {
                    silent_lus_command.executeLUS(product_dataset[4], is_silent[4]);
                    showInformationMessage("pause in silent LUS after CATProduct");
               }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("SampleLUS error (5) Exception : " + ex);
          }


          /******* CATDrawing dataset  ********/
          try
          {    
               if (drawing_dataset[5] != null)
               {
                    silent_lus_command.executeLUS(drawing_dataset[5], is_silent[5]);
                    showInformationMessage("pause in silent LUS after CATDrawing");
               }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("SampleLUS error (6) Exception : " + ex);
          }


          /******* other dataset  ********/
          try
          {   
               if (other[6] != null)
               {
                    silent_lus_command.executeLUS(other[6], is_silent[6]);
                    showInformationMessage("pause in silent LUS ");
               }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("SampleLUS error (7) Exception : " + ex);
          }


          silent_lus_command.stopProcess();

     }

     /**
      * is used to display an Error message
      * @param i_msg (I) the message to be displayed
      */
     private void showErrorMessage(final String i_msg)
     {
         ErrorWarningMessages.showErrorMessage(i_msg, _title);
     }

     /**
      * is used to display an Information message
      * @param i_msg (I) the message to display
      */
     private void showInformationMessage(final String i_msg)
     {
         ErrorWarningMessages.showInformationMessage(i_msg, _title);
     }
     /**
      * Sample of searching item to LUS.
      * read the query.txt file that contains the item_id, item_rev_id and silent mode of the selected item 
      * The first line contains the number of assembly to LUS
      * Then, for each assembly, we need 3 lines : item_id, item_rev_id and silent_mode
      *  example :
      *     2
      *     000010
      *     A
      *     true
      *     000020
      *     B
      *     false
      */
     protected int findItemToLUS()
     {
          String item_id = null;
          String item_rev_id = null;

          int return_value = 0;
          int nb_assy = 0;
          RandomAccessFile reader = null;
          File file = null;

          try
          {
               String file_path = "c:\\catiman_tmp\\tmp\\query.txt";
               file = new File(file_path);
               reader = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
               nb_assy = Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine()).intValue();

               is_silent = new boolean[nb_assy];
               item = new TCComponentItem[nb_assy];
               item_revision = new TCComponentItemRevision[nb_assy];
               part_dataset = new TCComponentDataset[nb_assy];
               product_dataset = new TCComponentDataset[nb_assy];
               drawing_dataset = new TCComponentDataset[nb_assy];
               other = new TCComponentForm[nb_assy];
               bom_window = new TCComponentBOMWindow[nb_assy];
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("error 0 - " + ex);
               return_value = -1;
          }

          for (int i = 0 ; i < (nb_assy) ; i++)
          {
               try
               {
                    item_id = reader.readLine();
                    item_rev_id = reader.readLine();
                    is_silent[i] = Boolean.valueOf(reader.readLine()).booleanValue();

                    // search item name item_id 
                    TCComponentItemType it = (TCComponentItemType)(session.getTypeComponent("Item"));
                    item[i] = it.find(item_id);

                    if (item[i] == null)
                    {
                         showErrorMessage("Error : item <" + item_id + ">not found");
                         return_value = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         // the item was found, search the correction item revision
                         AIFComponentContext[] revisions = item[i].getChildren();
                         TCComponentItemRevision revision_component = null;

                         for (int j = 0; j < revisions.length; j++)
                         {
                              InterfaceAIFComponent component = revisions[j].getComponent();
                              if (component instanceof TCComponentItemRevision)
                              {
                                   revision_component = (TCComponentItemRevision) component;

                                   if (revision_component.getProperty("item_revision_id").equals(item_rev_id))
                                   {
                                        item_revision[i] = revision_component;
                                        break;
                                   }
                              }
                         }

                         if (item_revision[i] == null)
                         {
                              showErrorMessage("Error : Item revision [" + item_rev_id + "] doesn't exist for item [" + item_id + "]");
                              return_value = -1;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                              // create the BOMWindow with the item revision previously found 
                              TCComponentBOMWindowType type = (TCComponentBOMWindowType)session.getTypeComponent("BOMWindow");
                              TCComponentRevisionRuleType rule = (TCComponentRevisionRuleType)session.getTypeComponent("RevisionRule");
                              bom_window[i] = type.create(rule.getDefaultRule());

                              /* Define the BOMWindow top line */
                              TCComponentBOMLine top_line = bom_window[i].setWindowTopLine(item[i], item_revision[i], null, null);
                         }
                    }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    showErrorMessage("error 1 - " + ex);
                    return_value = -1;
               }

               // search for a dataset (CATPart or CATProduct and/or CATDrawing)
               try
               {
                    int nb = item_revision[i].getChildrenCount();
                    if (nb > 0)
                    {
                         AIFComponentContext[] aif_comp_cont = item_revision[i].getChildren();

                         for (int j = 0 ; j < nb ; j++)
                         {
                              InterfaceAIFComponent int_aif_comp = aif_comp_cont[j].getComponent();


                              if (int_aif_comp.getType().equals("CATPart"))
                              {
                                   part_dataset[i] = (TCComponentDataset)int_aif_comp;
                              }
                              else if (int_aif_comp.getType().equals("CATProduct"))
                              {
                                   product_dataset[i] = (TCComponentDataset)int_aif_comp;
                              }
                              else if (int_aif_comp.getType().equals("CATDrawing"))
                              {
                                   drawing_dataset[i] = (TCComponentDataset)int_aif_comp;
                              }
                              else if (int_aif_comp.getType().equals("ItemRevision Master"))
                              {
                                   other[i] = (TCComponentForm)int_aif_comp;
                              }
                         }
                    }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    showErrorMessage("error 2 - " + ex);
                    return_value = -1;
               }
          }
          try
          {
               reader.close();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               showErrorMessage("error 3 - " + ex);
          }
          return return_value;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("Lets try this");
     SampleIndependentSilentLUS test = new SampleIndependentSilentLUS();
     //test.customerProcess();  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get TCSession.

**1) If you writing a Rich-Client Plugin**

```
//numTry - number of attemts    
private static TCSession getCurrentSession(int numTry) throws Exception {
        try {
            TCSession session = null;
            ISessionService iss=null;
            int numtry=numTry;
            while (iss==null && numtry>0) {
                iss = AifrcpPlugin.getSessionService();
                numtry--;
            }

            session=(TCSession)iss.getSession("com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCSession");
            return session;
            } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**2) If you writing a stand-alone application**, using SOA to work with Teamcenter API.

In this case, you need to connect teamcenter first. View "HelloTeamcenter" example in documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

did you get a solution for this?

SampleIndependentSilentLUS is a very good way of automating LUS process.but i prefer using the other class(SampleSilentLUS ) that can be called from command line because TCIC will automatically provide a TCSession

the session object you get from SOA(com.teamcenter.services.strong.core._2008_06.Session) is not compatible with RAC Session(com.teamcenter.rac.TCSession).

but if you use loose services(com.teamcenter.services.loose.core), i think you can simply typecast to TCSession